# Как вы планируете системы с асинхронными вызовами?

Tags: алгоритм, асинхронность, блок-схема

Планирую веб апп, где много асинхронных вызовов. Тут и юзер может хаотично на разные кнопки начать жать, и API ВКонтакта, Твиттера и прочих сервисов могут отвечать быстро или долго, и задачи ставятся в очередь, которая бывает пуста или занята надолго вперед. И многие элементы друг от друга зависят.

Обычная линейная блок-схема алгоритма, наверное, не подоходит. Или я не умею их правильно составлять и читать.

Как вы планируете такие вещи, чтобы любую хронологию событий наглядно рассмотреть?

Comment: А классическая sequence diagram не подойдёт?

Comment: @Alexander Serebrenik не пользовался раньше. Почитал вики, не понял, можно ли на одной диаграмме отобразить, например, два разных сценария, в зависимости от того, какой из двух параллельных процессов завершился раньше.

Comment: асинхронно!=паралельно

Comment: Я имею в виду, запустил_А, запустил_Б. И их коллбэки по-разному должны себя вести, в зависимости от готовности другого.

Comment: ну так, обычно асинхронные коллбэки сходятся в общей памяти, т.е. состояние вполне предсказуемое, если их состояние зависит друг от друга используют флаги или просто оценивают состояние системы. Я про что  - нет необходимости прям как-то особо рассматривать этот случай.